# Is possible to get the percentage value on query using count and group by?

Tags: postgresql, count, sum, window-functions, percentage

I have a Query:

```
select no_tipo_origem, 
       count(*) total 
from table 
group by no_tipo_origem
```

The result is:

```
tipo 1 |  25
tipo 2 | 133
tipo 3 |  48
```

I need to calculate the percentage like this:

```
tipo 1 |  25 | 12.1
tipo 2 | 133 | 64.5
tipo 3 |  48 | 23.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide each total with the sum of all totals which you can get with `SUM()` window function:

```
select no_tipo_origem, 
       count(*) total,
       round(100.0 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (), 1) percentage 
from tablename 
group by no_tipo_origem
order by no_tipo_origem
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9f850f9064cbd987f0c25df6d5df24fc).